# Get Ansicon working on Console2 (Windows 7, 64 bit)

Tags: windows, rspec, console2, ansicon

I was wondering how you would get Ansicon working on Console2. Currently, tere is color when I run cmd.exe and colors show up (ie. Rspec).

BUT, i have tried to use Console2 `(Settings, Tabs, Shell -> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe "C:/Ansicon/ansicon.exe", C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ansicon, etc... )` it just doesn't quite work. I have also tried variations such as `"C:/Ansicon/ansicon.exe"`, but it shrinks up the Console2 window.

Now here's the kicker..... after I open a tab in Console2 and verify there isnt color, by running Rspec, I run "ansicon" again and execute the same command, and there would be color...

This might be a really simple question, but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your starting command must be

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k Ansicon -p
```

Also, why not to try ConEmu? It can ANSI internally.